# Python: and operator doesn't seem to work in while loop

Tags: python

I have code like this

```
from random import randint
def rand(p):
    a = randint(0, p)
    b = randint(0, p)
    while (a != 501) and (b != 370):
        a = randint(0, p)
        b = randint(0, p)
    print(a, b)
rand(1000)
```

After some iterations it gets out of the loop, but it doesn't print 501 **and** 370. It always prints 501 **or** 370. I have no clue why this is happening. I tried without parentheses in while loop and to put everything in them and It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Look at one of the sample outputs you get (let's say `501 0`) and ask if it satisfies the `while` condition.  What's the boolean value of `(501 != 501) and (0 != 370)`?

Comment: your while loop is doing "while both of them are false, randomize again" so if one hits the value, it goes out of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this logically:

- If `a` is 501, then `a != 501` is `False`, and `False and anything` is `False`, so the whole thing is false and the loop terminates, regardless of the value of `b`
- If `b` is 370, then `b != 370` is `False`, and with the same reasoning, the loop terminates regardless of the value of `a`

What you're looking for is `a != 501 or b != 370`:

- If `a` is 501, then `a != 501` is `False`, but if `b` is not 370, then `b != 370` is `True`, meaning the whole thing is `True`, letting the loop continue
- Likewise, if `b` is 370, and `a` is not 501, the loop continues for the same reasoning
- If `a` is 501 and `b` is 370, you get `False or False`, which is `False`, so the loop terminates.

This can also be derived from [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

- You want to stop when `a == 501 and b == 370`, so you loop while `not (a == 501 and b == 370)`
- You can apply De Morgan's theorem to "distribute" the `not` and flip the operation from `and` to `or` to get `(not (a == 501)) or (not (b == 370))`
- You can replace the ugly `not (x == y)` with the prettier `x != y` to get `a != 501 or b != 370`

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean `(a != 501) or (b != 370)`, which is equivalent to `not (a == 501 and b == 370)`, which is also equivalent to `(a, b) != (501, 370)` (that's how I would write it).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `or` instead `and` in while loop.

```
from random import randint
def rand(p):
    a = randint(0, p)
    b = randint(0, p)
    while (a != 501) or (b != 370):
        a = randint(0, p)
        b = randint(0, p)
    print(a, b)
rand(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap out the `and` for an `or`:

From:

```
from random import randint
def rand(p):
    a = randint(0, p)
    b = randint(0, p)
    while (a != 501) and (b != 370):
        a = randint(0, p)
        b = randint(0, p)
    print(a, b)
rand(1000)
```

to:

```
from random import randint
def rand(p):
    a = randint(0, p)
    b = randint(0, p)
    while (a != 501) or (b != 370):
        a = randint(0, p)
        b = randint(0, p)
    print(a, b)
rand(1000)
```

When you say

```
while (a != 501) and (b != 370)
```

Tells python to only keep looking if *both* `a != 501` and `b != 370`, so if `a` equals to `501`, then regardless of what `b` equals to, the loop will end.